# Login Entity Relation Diagram: Review and Opinions

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, entity-relationship, erd

I've made a try of an ERD, to model a login system to manage employees, accounts, netkeys, usernames and passwords in an enterprise, but I still think something's missing or could be improved.

So for this problem consists of linking a certain company and its employees with their respective account numbers, usernames, netkeys and passwords to enter websites of other companies and banks.

An employee can guard several accounts from a single bank or company, and the company is related to several banks and companies, so the employee ends up having several accounts from several banks.

Likewise, and depending on the position that the employee has, different types of permissions and privileges are granted.

Each account is associated with a unique netkey and username, and each netkey has a serial number (or id).

[Here is my first try to model my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOHf8.png)

Comment: Looks reasonable.  Have you tested your ERD?  You test your ERD by writing SQL queries that retrieve or update data that meet the requirements of the application. If you can't write the queries, rework your ERD until you can.

Comment: I certainly haven't tested my ERD, and I don't really know SQL very well at the moment, but I'll try to investigate and look for more info on the subject to update on this problem.